# google charts dashboard load fail

Tags: charts, dashboard, google-visualization

This question might be the silliest of all, however im trying to just make the code run which is directly from google chart guide website and surprisingly its not working.

I have copy pasted the code from the below URL and tried to run it in firefox browser. It gave me below error and i couldn't find any error in the log as well. Not sure what went wrong.
Code source : https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#using-controls--and-dashboards

**Code**

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['controls']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates a dashboard, a range slider and a pie chart,
      // passes in the data and draws it.
      function drawDashboard() {

        // Create our data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Name', 'Donuts eaten'],
          ['Michael' , 5],
          ['Elisa', 7],
          ['Robert', 3],
          ['John', 2],
          ['Jessica', 6],
          ['Aaron', 1],
          ['Margareth', 8]
        ]);

        // Create a dashboard.
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

        // Create a range slider, passing some options
        var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'filter_div',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Donuts eaten'
          }
        });

        // Create a pie chart, passing some options
        var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'PieChart',
          'containerId': 'chart_div',
          'options': {
            'width': 300,
            'height': 300,
            'pieSliceText': 'value',
            'legend': 'right'
          }
        });

        // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
        // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
        // given the chosen slider range.
        dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, pieChart);

        // Draw the dashboard.
        dashboard.draw(data);
      }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!--Div that will hold the dashboard-->
    <div id="dashboard_div">
        <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
        <div id="filter_div"></div>
        <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the documentation and examples are quite stale at this point.
with recent releases of `loader.js`, the `'corechart'` package needs to be included for the charts to work.

see following, working example...

```js
// Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['controls', 'corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

// Callback that creates and populates a data table,
// instantiates a dashboard, a range slider and a pie chart,
// passes in the data and draws it.
function drawDashboard() {

  // Create our data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Name', 'Donuts eaten'],
    ['Michael' , 5],
    ['Elisa', 7],
    ['Robert', 3],
    ['John', 2],
    ['Jessica', 6],
    ['Aaron', 1],
    ['Margareth', 8]
  ]);

  // Create a dashboard.
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
      document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

  // Create a range slider, passing some options
  var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
    'containerId': 'filter_div',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Donuts eaten'
    }
  });

  // Create a pie chart, passing some options
  var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'PieChart',
    'containerId': 'chart_div',
    'options': {
      'width': 300,
      'height': 300,
      'pieSliceText': 'value',
      'legend': 'right'
    }
  });

  // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
  // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
  // given the chosen slider range.
  dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, pieChart);

  // Draw the dashboard.
  dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<!--Div that will hold the dashboard-->
<div id="dashboard_div">
    <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
    <div id="filter_div"></div>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code works like a charm. Thank you for your time and effort. I guess as i have used one of the chart type of corechart (bar, column, line, area, stepped area, bubble, pie, donut, combo, candlestick, histogram, scatter) i should load the package as dependency.  I need Controls  package as i have used i have NumberRangeFilter.